# Mongoexport error : couldn't connect to [127.0.0.1:27017] couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongoexport

I am trying to export local database collection. Usually I use robomongo 3T to check database.
I started my meteor project on 3000 port. 
Started meteor mongo and ran,

```
meteor mongo
```

The output was,

```
 local   0.003GB
 meteor  0.002GB
```

Then tried,

```
mongoexport --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 --db meteor --collection faqs --out myCollection.json
```

But it giving error,

```
couldn't connect to [127.0.0.1:27017] couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Tried to find logs in /var/logs/mongodb but there is no mongodb directory present.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check to make sure the mongo server is running? If you're on a Linux server, try "ps -ef | grep mongod" at the command line.

Comment: Output:iassure+  6083  6025  0 09:29 pts/7    00:00:08 /home/iassureit/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.19lrjzg.xk02l++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 --dbpath /var/meteor/scodebase/.meteor/local/db --oplogSize 8 --replSet meteor --noauth --nojournal
iassure+  7583  7550  0 09:45 pts/14   00:00:00 grep --color=auto mongod

Comment: start your mongod service by `sudo service mongod start`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your "grep ... mongod", I don't see mongod in your ps output anywhere. Do you have root access to the machine? If so, run "sudo mongod" to start up your mongo server.

Comment: I am using meteor for development so I never installed mongod server. Meteor itself provides mongodb. Tried installing mongod by apt, got error ERROR: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist, now focusing on resolving it.

Comment: Okay @Rashmi, looks like you'll need to take on your own from here. Good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

ERROR: dbpath (/data/db/):
This is present in your configuration file usually located at etc in Linux.
just open a file vi /etc/mongod.conf
there is a line /data/db provide a path to directory in front of it.
After this re-start MongoDB instance, maybe using command "service mongod start".
This should resolve the issue.